# c sscanf and SCNu64 compile error

Tags: c

I don't understand the below error message when I compile this code. I couldn't find out what wrong with it.

```
Description Resource Path Location
Type expected ‘)’ before ‘SCNu64’.  

#include <inttypes.h> 
int calc_rate(uint64_t *rate, char val[], char mult[]) {
     int rc = sscanf(val, "%" SCNu64 "%2s", rate, mult);  
}
```

Comment: Have you included `<inttypes.h>` to get the `SCNu64` macro defined?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `uint64_t` and falling off the end of a value returning function is undefined behavior.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour yes it is. corrected

Comment: If you have both `<inttypes.h>` and `<stdio.h>` included, then the code fragment shown compiles cleanly. (You can't call `sscanf()` legally unless there's a prototype in scope.) That means the problem is in the code prior to what you are showing. Or it means that your compiler doesn't provide support for exactly 64-bit types, which is rather unlikely unless you're on a relatively obscure mainframe, or you aren't compiling in C99 or C11 mode.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks. Problem solve. Want me to mark you the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have both `<inttypes.h>` and `<stdio.h>` included, then the code fragment shown compiles cleanly. (You can't call `sscanf()` legally unless there's a prototype in scope.) That means the problem is in the code prior to what you are showing. Or it means that your compiler doesn't provide support for exactly 64-bit types, which is rather unlikely unless you're on a relatively obscure mainframe, or you aren't compiling in C99 or C11 mode.